# how to generate date and time in seconds

Tags: ruby

I am currently saving in a PostGres Database a timestamp which follow the format

```
"2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773"
```

I would like to able to translate this date and time in seconds and be able to do the operation in the other way from sec to : "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773"

Any idea how to do it in ruby

Answer (score 0):

I think you would convert it to a ruby timestamp with `Time.parse`, then get the Epoch time in seconds with `strftime("%s")` like so:

```
time = "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773"
time.strftime("%s")
```

There's a full list of options to pass to `strftime` here: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

And there is more detail on `Time.parse` here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html

Answer (score 0):

```
date = DateTime.parse "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773"
=> Thu, 17 Aug 2017 20:42:52 +0000

date.to_i
=> 1503002572
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to able to translate this date and time in seconds [...]

If you have a string, you can [`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) it into a `Time` instance:

```
require 'time'

t = Time.parse('2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773')
#=> 2017-08-17 20:42:52 +0200
```

The seconds (since the epoch) can then be extracted via [`to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-i-to_f):

```
sec = t.to_f
#=> 1502995372.7247732
```

> [...] and be able to do the operation in the other way

The seconds can in turn be passed to [`Time::at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-c-at):

```
 t = Time.at(sec)
 #=> 2017-08-17 20:42:52 +0200
```

Which again returns a `Time` instance. This can be formatted via [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
 t.strftime('%FT%T.%6N')
 #=> "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773"
```